# Why I am getting error as "not all arguments converted during string formatting" during this python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = input("Enter your number: ")
if n%2 != 0:
    print("Weird")
elif n%2 == 0:
    if n>1 and n<6:
        print("Not weird")
    elif n>=6 and n<=20:
        print("Weird")
    elif n>20:
        print("Not Weird")
```

While running this code I got the error message. I could not find the reason.

Comment: You forgot to convert `n` to a number. When applied to a string, `%` is the substitution operator, not the remainder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't convert your input to integer.

so instead of calculating remainder of `n` by 2. , You are get into string formatting in line `if n%2 != 0:`

The old way of formatting string was :

```
name = 'John'
print('hi %s' % name )
```

Answer (score 0):

SorusH is right, you didn't convert your input to integer, you should try something like

```
n = int(input("Enter your number: "))
```

to convert the input into an integer